# Method returning different type if block_given?

Tags: ruby, return-type

Would it be bad practice to have a method that returns `self` on `block_given?` and a different type if a block was not provided?

**The example:**

`Config#item` will return the `item` if a block is not given, and will return `Config` if it is given.

```
class Item
  :attr_reader :key

  def initialize(key)
    @key = key
  end

  def do_stuff
    puts "#{key} doing some stuff"
    self
  end
end

class Config
  attr_reader :items

  def initialize
    @items = {}
  end

  def item(key)
    itm = @items[key] ||= Item.new(key)
    if block_given?
      yield(itm)
      self
    else
      itm
    end
  end
end
```

**Usage:**

```
cnf = Config.new
cnf.item("foo") do |itm|
  itm.do_stuff
end

.item("bar") do |itm|
  itm.do_stuff
end

foo = .item("foo").do_stuff
cnf.item("baz").do_stuff
foo.do_stuff
```

The model is meant to use the same method `item` as a getter and as a way to refer to an item that needs to be configured or which configuration needs to be reopened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would it be bad practice to have a method that returns `self` on `block_given?` and a different type if a block was not provided?

No. In fact, there is an *extremely* well-known example of a method that has this *exact* signature: `each`. `each` returns `self` if a block is given, and an `Enumerator` when no block is given. In fact, many methods in `Enumerable` return an `Enumerator` when no block is given and something else if there is a block.

(I am actually surprised that you haven't encountered `each` or `Enumerable` so far.)

Comment: fair enough as the idea comes from it :). Just doubting because the essential role that `each` performs in `Enumerable` gives the impression of it being a special case (so to say... rather than a common case). But your answer appears to be more to the point, because aside of using blocks as callbacks (to delay code execution or make code more readable), the rest mostly relates to iterators; which in its core seems to always have an `Enumerator` (if I am not mistaken).

Answer (score 1):

Not at all, as long as the users of your method have adequate understanding of this.  Documentation helps quite significantly in these situations.

Consider the Ruby Standard Library.  Many methods return different types based on their inputs and `block_given?`, such as [`Enumerable#map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map), [`Hash#each`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-i-each), and [`Range#step`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Range.html#method-i-step).

Like the standard library authors, you have to decide whether you prefer a compact interface to your class/model or consistent behavior from your methods.  There are always tradeoffs to make, and you have numerous strong examples of each of these to draw from within the Ruby Standard Library.